# Session Android App, like web apps

Tags: android, session

I have a web social network (located on a webserver) which has an API, and I'm trying to develop an adroid app for it. Now I've already can sign (send 'user and pass' and authenticate) on this API. For this I have a method sendLogin(String user,String pass) that returns me a user object.

My question is:

After this steps, I wanna go to other screen(main menu, for example). How is the best way to persist the user obect on my app?

For example:

1. Login screen: sign in on API
2. API: athenticate data
3. Login screen: create a user object
4. Login screen: calls the main Menu
5. User: wanna see her data (name,email, gender, age)
6. Profile screen: show this data

The user object was created on Login.java but it should persist on many screen (all application's life cycle).

I've used this. But with this solution I'll do this in many place, I will terrible to change and maintain.

```
public void loginSucceed(User user){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
        //passa parametros de uma activity pra outra
        intent.putExtra("id",user.getId());
        intent.putExtra("user",user.getUsername());
        intent.putExtra("email",user.getEmail());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I there a best way?

Answer (score 2):

Intents are a good way for this but if you don't want to use that you can override the Application class and put the user class in there so you can retrieve it in any activity.

Looking at your intent code your user class doesn't implement parcelable as you are retrieving it field by field. If you make the class implement parcelable you just can do intent.putParcelable(group)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: But with parceble I'll need call intent on every screens and I don't need do it. Imagine an app with 40 class, I'll need code it in all classes. :( On a web app, we uses a session to persist whatever we want. I only know how can I persist user an object into my app.

Comment: on a webpage you have to load the session everytime also and in an app you have to load the parcelable from the intent everytime which is just 1 line of code. What you even could do is make a class e.g CustomActivity which overrides activity. In that class you put the code to read and write the user from the intent. And you let all other activities extends the CustomActivity class instead of the normal activity. On that way yuo only have to code it once

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way to do it. Store an HttpContext in the application object and as you go from activity to activity and need to access your social website, you can access the cookies stored in CookieStore (in the application object associated with the HttpContext) and use that to access your website.

[Here is some code on using HttpContext](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java)

Read this thread on creating and working with the Application object

[Android Application Object](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/502fe58d8ed44102/1fce6026591d083b?lnk=gst&q=Application%20object#1fce6026591d083b)

This is very similar to what you'd be doing with a web application so you can transfer your web knowledge to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep your application light weighted and dynamic you should use java beans

```
class CommonBean implements Serializable
{
     String name,gender;
     int age;
    // generate getter and setter for the variables.
}
```